# React Native AppLoading without Expo

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-navigation-v2

I've used expo for a while now and have switched to react-native-init without expo.

I've been very comfortable working without expo (thanks Github) but somehow I am unable to find a solution with much googling, for a similar feature to AppLoading in Expo ( https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/app-loading ). Maybe I'm not using the correct keywords, I keep getting results for react native fast image etc which just preload images from cache.

I've already set up the Launch screen in Xcode, **I would like to network request, load some data into my redux store, preload images and some fonts, before my Launch screen switches to my first screen**.

Can someone provide me with a solution or a link to the solution?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[react-native-splash-screen](https://github.com/crazycodeboy/react-native-splash-screen) meets your requirement!

Answer (score 4):

As of 2022,

You may try [react-native-bootsplash](https://github.com/zoontek/react-native-bootsplash)

In case, `react-native-splash-screen` is not suitable for you.

Answer (score 0):

I managed it to just do a simple loading placeholder. While loading you have loadingState == true. If it finished to fetch user data e.g. it will load your normal screen, navigation or whatever

```
  if (loginState == true){
    return(
      <View style={{flex: 1, justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center", backgroundColor: "#000000"}}>
        <Text style={{color: "#FFFFFF", fontSize: 27, fontFamily: "Poppins-SemiBold"}}>Loading</Text>
        <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#FFFFFF" />
      </View>
    )
  };
```

Comment: You've proposed an incorrect solution to the original poster's question. Your code would still display a white/blank splash screen for a fraction of a second while the user auth is loading. We are trying to customize the background color that's shown for only a fraction of a second (right before the app starts running).